Why is my "RangetoHTML" not pasting into email correctly?
I am trying to get Excel to send multiple emails, including a list of tasks that are assigned to them.
I am trying to do this by having a list of all the people across the teams, including their emails and line managers. Lookups set the variables for the names to filter to and the corresponding email addresses, the sheet then filters to that person in the variable.
The part I am struggling with is pasting the range into the email body. As whilst the email is constructed correctly, the range is displayed as what I can only describe as HTML 'gibberish', instead of a paste of the worksheet contents.
I am also unable to get the ".send" command to work, but ".display" works fine. Beyond that, the email is constructed as I would like, it is just the paste from excel that isn't displaying properly.
I will include all the code below. The sub macros are in a module together, and the function macro is in a separate module; in case that makes any difference I'm not aware of.
`Option Explicit`
`Sub Send_Email_Condition()`
`Dim xSheet As Worksheet, tSheet As Worksheet`
`Dim mAddress As String, mSubject As String, eName As String, tName As String, lAddress As String`
`Dim eRow As Long, tRow As Long, x As Long
`Dim rng As Range`

`Set xSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Lookups")`
`Set tSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tasks")`

`With xSheet`
`eRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row`

`For x = 2 To eRow`

`tName = xSheet.Cells(x, 3)`
`tSheet.Range("$A$1:$CC$1").AutoFilter Field:=61, Criteria1:=tName`
`tRow = tSheet.Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row`
`Set rng = Sheets("Tasks").Range("A1:CC" & tRow)`

`        If tRow > 1 Then`

`        mAddress = xSheet.Cells(x, 4)`
`        lAddress = xSheet.Cells(x, 5)`
`        mSubject = "Outstanding assigned Tasks"`
`        eName = xSheet.Cells(x, 3)`

`        Call Send_Email_With_Multiple_Condition(mAddress, mSubject, eName, lAddress, rng)`

`        End If`

`Next x`

`End With`

`End Sub`

`Sub Send_Email_With_Multiple_Condition(mAddress As String, mSubject As String, eName As String, lAddress As String, rng As Range)`
`Dim pApp As Object`
`Dim pMail As Object`
`Set pApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")`
`Set pMail = pApp.CreateItem(0)`
`With pMail`
`.To = mAddress`
`.CC = lAddress`
`.BCC = ""`
`.Subject = mSubject`
`.body = eName & "," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Please find attached your outstanding assigned NCR tasks." _`
`& vbNewLine & vbNewLine & RangetoHTML(rng) _`
`& vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Please review at your earliest convenience."`
`.display 'would prefer to use .Send here but I can't get it to work`
`End With`
`Set pMail = Nothing`
`Set pApp = Nothing`
`End Sub`

`Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)`
`' Works in Excel 2000, Excel 2002, Excel 2003, Excel 2007, Excel 2010, Outlook 2000,     Outlook 2002, Outlook 2003, Outlook 2007, and Outlook 2010.`
`    Dim FSO As Object`
`    Dim ts As Object`
`    Dim TempFile As String`
`    Dim TempWB As Workbook`

`    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "/" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"`

`    ' Copy the range and create a workbook to receive the data.`
`    rng.Copy`
`    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)`
`    With TempWB.Sheets(1)`
`        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8`
`        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False`
`        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False`
`        .Cells(1).Select`
`        Application.CutCopyMode = False`
`        On Error Resume Next`
`        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True`
`        .DrawingObjects.Delete`
`        On Error GoTo 0`
`    End With`

`    ' Publish the sheet to an .htm file.`
`    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _`
`         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _`
`         Filename:=TempFile, _`
`         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _`
`         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _`
`         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)`
`        .Publish (True)`
`    End With`

`    ' Read all data from the .htm file into the RangetoHTML subroutine.`
`    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")`
`    Set ts = FSO.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)`
`    RangetoHTML = ts.ReadAll`
`    ts.Close`
`    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _`
`                          "align=left x:publishsource=")`

`    ' Close TempWB.`
`    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False`

`    ' Delete the htm file.`
`    Kill TempFile`

`    Set ts = Nothing`
`    Set FSO = Nothing`
`    Set TempWB = Nothing`
`End Function`

A snippet of the type of 'gibberish' being pasted is as below:
<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" 
xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"> 
<head> 
<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=windows- 
1252"> 
<meta name=ProgId content=Excel.Sheet> 
<meta name=Generator content="Microsoft Excel 15"> 
<link rel=File-List href="01-12-24%208-41-32_files/filelist.xml"> 
<style id="Sheet14_11683_Styles"> 
<!--table 
        {mso-displayed-decimal-separator:"\."; 
        mso-displayed-thousand-separator:"\,";} 
.xl1511683 
    {padding-top:1px; 
    padding-right:1px; 
    padding-left:1px; 
    mso-ignore:padding; 
    color:black; 
    font-size:11.0pt; 
    font-weight:400; 
    font-style:normal; 
    text-decoration:none; 
    font-family:Calibri, sans-serif; 
    mso-font-charset:0; 
    mso-number-format:General; 
    text-align:general; 
    vertical-align:bottom; 
    mso-background-source:auto; 
    mso-pattern:auto; 
    white-space:nowrap;} 
.xl6311683 
    {padding-top:1px; 
    padding-right:1px; 
    padding-left:1px; 
    mso-ignore:padding; 
    color:black; 
    font-size:11.0pt; 
    font-weight:400; 
    font-style:normal; 
    text-decoration:none; 
    font-family:Calibri, sans-serif; 
    mso-font-charset:0; 
    mso-number-format:General; 
    text-align:general; 
    vertical-align:top; 
    mso-background-source:auto; 
    mso-pattern:auto; 
    white-space:nowrap;} 
--> 
</style> 
</head> 
<body> 
<!--[if !excel]>&nbsp;&nbsp;<![endif]--> 
<!--The following information was generated by Microsoft Excel's Publish as Web 
Page wizard.--> 
<!--If the same item is republished from Excel, all information between the DIV tags will be replaced.--> 
<!-----------------------------> 
<!--START OF OUTPUT FROM EXCEL PUBLISH AS WEB PAGE WIZARD --> 
<!-----------------------------> 
<div id="Sheet14_11683" align=left x:publishsource="Excel"> 
<table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 width=5303 style='border-collapse: collapse;table-layout:fixed;width:3977pt'> 
 <col width=64 span=60 style='width:48pt'> 
 <col width=183 style='mso-width-source:userset;mso-width-alt:6692;width:137pt'> 
 <col width=64 span=20 style='width:48pt'> 
 <tr height=20 style='height:15.0pt'> 
 <td height=20 class=xl6311683 width=64 
 style='height:15.0pt;width:48pt'>Created 
 B<span style='display:none'>y</span></td>
<td class=xl6311683 width=64 style='width:48pt'>Changed <span style='display:none'>By</span></td> 


Can you check your outlook option that Compose mail in HTML or just plain text format?

Thanks for your reply. The option "Compose messages in this format:" is set to HTML. Is that not correct?

That is correct.

That is already set to HTML, so something else must be causing the issue. Any idea why the .send command would also not work?

.HTMLBody not .body.

Oh god. Thank you. It works now. Can't believe I missed that.
